# minimum number of steps to reduce number to 1

Tags: algorithm, math, dynamic-programming

Given any number n, and three operations on n:

1. add 1
2. subtract 1
3. divide by 2 if the number is even

I want to find the minimum number of the above operations to reduce n to 1. I have tried dynamic progamming approach, also BFS with pruning, but n can be very large (10^300) and I do not know how to make my algorithm faster. The greedy approach (divide by 2 if even and subtract 1 if odd) also does not give the optimal result. Is another solution exists?

Comment: `The greedy approach ... does not give the optimal result` ... can you give a number for which this is not optimal?

Comment: 15, greedy will give 6 (14 -> 7 -> 6 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1) but optimal is 5 (16 -> 8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1)

Comment: Sounds like you want to approach a power of 2 if possible.

Comment: Do a variant of the greedy approach, but at each step check whether it's quicker to get to the nearest power of 2 and divide until 1.

Comment: Problem statement needs to be more clear.  You want min number of above operations, but can i use other operations (e.g. multiply, add two numbers) to calculate the min number of steps?

Comment: Not sure if this is optimal but it seems whenever there are 4 or more ones in the binary representation at the end do an add step, otherwise do subtract or divide.

Comment: @trincot You don't understand my question. For example, The answer proposed by Aylon will calculate the number of operations needed. But to figure that out, the solution uses array indexing (which requires multiplication and addition of two numbers), as well as min operation, which requires subtraction of two numbers.

Comment: @JoelLee, indeed I misunderstood your earlier comment. Thanks for having clarified.

Comment: See also the [3n+1 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture): n even -> n / 2, n odd -> 3n+1. Afaik it's still unsolved.

Comment: For reference, this is a problem from the foobar.withgoogle.com game. Even the 10^300 problem size is taken straight from there. Curiously, the proposed solution (to which I also arrived independently) does not pass all test cases.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

There is a pattern which allows you to know the optimal next step in constant time. In fact, there can be cases where there are two equally optimal choices -- in that case one of them can be derived in constant time.

If you look at the binary representation of *n*, and its least significant bits, you can make some conclusions about which operation is leading to the solution. In short:

- if the least significant bit is zero, then divide by 2
- if *n* is 3, or the 2 least significant bits are 01, then subtract
- In all other cases: add.

#### Proof

If the least significant bit is zero, the next operation should be the division by 2. We could instead try 2 additions and then a division, but then that same result can be achieved in two steps: divide and add. Similarly with 2 subtractions. And of course, we can ignore the useless subsequent add & subtract steps (or vice versa). So if the final bit is 0, division is the way to go.

Then the remaining 3-bit patterns are like `**1`. There are four of them. Let's write `a011` to denote a number that ends with bits `011` and has a set of prefixed bits that would represent the value *a*:

- `a001`: adding one would give `a010`, after which a division should occur: `a01`: 2 steps taken. We would not want to subtract one now, because that would lead to `a00`, which we could have arrived at in two steps from the start (subtract 1 and divide). So again we add and divide to get `a1`, and for the same reason we repeat that again, giving: `a+1`. This took 6 steps, but leads to a number that could be arrived at in 5 steps (subtract 1, divide 3 times, add 1), so clearly, we should not perform the addition. Subtraction is always better.
- `a111`: addition is equal or better than subtraction. In 4 steps we get `a+1`. Subtraction and division would give `a11`. Adding now would be inefficient compared to the initial addition path, so we repeat this subtract/divide twice and get `a` in 6 steps. If `a` ends in 0, then we could have done this in 5 steps (add, divide three times, subtract), if `a` ends in a 1, then even in 4. So Addition is always better.
- `a101`: subtraction and double division leads to `a1` in 3 steps. Addition and division leads to `a11`. To now subtract and divide would be inefficient, compared to the subtraction path, so we add and divide twice to get `a+1` in 5 steps. But with the subtraction path, we could reach this in 4 steps. So subtraction is always better.
- `a011`: addition and double division leads to `a1`. To get `a` would take 2 more steps (5), to get `a+1`: one more (6). Subtraction, division, subtraction, double division leads to `a` (5), to get `a+1` would take one more step (6). So addition is at least as good as subtraction. There is however one case not to overlook: if *a* is 0, then the subtraction path reaches the solution half-way, in 2 steps, while the addition path takes 3 steps. So addition is always leading to the solution, except when *n* is 3: then subtraction should be chosen.

So for odd numbers the second-last bit determines the next step (except for 3).

#### Python Code

This leads to the following algorithm (Python), which needs one iteration for each step, making for O(log) iterations. If we consider that basic arithmetic operations on large integers have a log complexity, this brings us to a time complexity of O(log²):

```
def stepCount(n):
    count = 0
    while n > 1:
        if n % 2 == 0:             # bitmask: *0
            n = n // 2
        elif n == 3 or n % 4 == 1: # bitmask: 01
            n = n - 1
        else:                      # bitmask: 11
            n = n + 1
        count += 1
    return count
```

See it run on [repl.it](https://repl.it/DddQ).

#### JavaScript Snippet

Here is a version where you can input a value for *n* and let the snippet produce the number of steps:

```js
function stepCount(n) {
    var count = 0n;
    while (n > 1n) {
        if (n % 2n == 0) {                    // bitmask: *0
            n /= 2n;
        } else if (n == 3n || n % 4n == 1n) { // bitmask: 01
            n--;
        } else {                              // bitmask: 11
            n++;
        }
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

// I/O
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var calc = document.getElementById('calc');

calc.onclick = function () {
  var n = BigInt(input.value);
  var res = stepCount(n);
  output.textContent = res;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" value="123549811245">
<button id="calc">Calculate steps</button><br>
Result: <span id="output"></span>
```

This script uses `BigInt` typed values to allow for arbitrary large integers as is the case in Python.

Comment: This seems to need a really huge cache. the number can be as big as 10^300

Comment: I rewrote my answer completely. I believe it is now the fastest solution posted. It needs no cache, no recursion.

Comment: Nice algorithm, avoids unnecessary "tail recursion". Minor edit suggestion: Remove "Obviously," from your proof. Makes intuitive sense, but not obvious and, in fact, requires proof (which you did).

Comment: First, @trincot this is an excellent answer, so thank you! I was wondering if you could talk about what led you limit your scope to only three bits?

Comment: I don't remember how I came to that... I suppose it is one of those peculiar things of the human brain: you try a few things (like using the number of 1 bits), have some subconscious intuitions going on, and after several failing ideas there is the successful one bubbling up which turns out to hold up when analysing all possible scenarios. I might have looked at the 4 ending bits before the final answer, realizing the proof could be given with only 3, although the second bullet point actually still talks about the 4th bit.

Comment: Also, I am not really grasping why you are trying to get to `a+1` and why you are avoiding `a00` in the first bullet point. Also maybe you can point me in the direction of some resources to help me understand how `(a1 + 1) / 10 = a+1`. Does `a+1` represent some sort of signed binary number, or maybe a remainder?

Comment: @Will, the cases where the last bit is 0 (like `a00`) are dealt with in the first paragraph of the proof. For `a+1`. `a` could be anything, but let's assume it is 101. So `a1` is 1011.  Adding one to `a1` is then 1011+1 = 1100. Dividing by 2 gives 110, which indeed is 101+1 (`a+1`). `a` is the number you get when chopping off the 3 rightmost bits after the original number.

Comment: I made a breadth first search to confirm this answer and it works out for the first 1400 integers. Makes sense upon inspection. With the 2^x line in kind should we choose 1(first bit), 2(first two bits), 4 (three bits) or 8(four) or higher powers of 2 as a filter? Choosing 1 or two wouldn’t filter anything. 4 (3 sig bits) is the first that filters anything and any higher power is only redundant. Great answer.

Comment: @trincot I am working on a similar problem, where I have to reach a number n from 1 in minimum steps. My list of allowed operations are slightly more complex. Apart from +1, -1 I have where *2, /2 and the last operation where I can sort the digits of the number in descending order. I tried BFS approach but got TLE (obviously), Then I came across this solution of yours. Can you help me?? Problem link : https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/food-delivery-service/problem

Comment: It is better to post your attempt as a new question.

Comment: @trincot In the case of a011, how do you move from a1 to a+1 in 1 step? a1+1=(a+1)0, and a1-1=a0

Comment: Actually I wrote up an alternative proof, can you take a look @trincot
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57386889/5096422

Comment: @JaySchauer, The move is not from `a1` to `a+1` in one step. I had a typo in the number between parentheses (the accumulated number of steps), which gave the impression the step was from `a1`, while it really is from `a`. So its "(6)", not "(4)". Thanks for having spotted it ;-)

Comment: This answer is O(log(n)) time complexity only when the input fits integer. With BigNum (long) the complexety multiplies by log(n) / (length of integer in bits).

Comment: @StanislavGerman-Evtushenko, I updated my answer to include this aspect. But note that the length of a Big Integer in bits is O(log), so *"log(n) / (length of integer in bits)"* is O(1) for Big Integer types (that have a dynamic size). But it is true we have to factor in O(log) for arithmetic operations on big integers with  bits.

Comment: "length of integer in bits", not "length of big integer", either way its O(log^2(n)) as in your updated answer

Answer (score 7):

**In summary:**

- If n is even, divide by 2
- If n is 3 or its least significant bits are 01, subtract.
- If n's least significant bits are 11, add.

Repeat these operations on n until you reach 1, counting the number of operations performed. This is guaranteed to give the correct answer.

As an alternative to [the proof from @trincot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39589499/5096422), here is one that has less cases and is hopefully more clear:

**Proof:**

**Case 1: n is even**

Let y be the value of the number after performing some operations on it. To start, y = n.

1. Assume that dividing n by 2 is not the optimal approach.
2. Then either add or subtract an even number of times

   1. Mixing addition and subtraction will result in unnecessary operations, so only either one is done.
   2. An even number must be added/subtracted, since stopping on an odd number would force continued adding or subtracting.
3. Let 2k, where k is some integer, be the number of additions or subtractions performed

   1. Limit k when subtracting so that n - 2k >= 2.
4. After adding/subtracting, y = n + 2k, or y = n - 2k.
5. Now divide. After dividing, y = n/2 + k, or y = n/2 - k
6. 2k + 1 operations have been performed. But the same result could have have been achieved in 1 + k operations, by dividing first then adding or subtracting k times.
7. Thus the assumption that dividing is not the optimal approach was wrong, and dividing is the optimal approach.

**Case 2: n is odd**

The goal here is to show that when faced with an odd n, either adding or subtracting will result in less operations to reach a given state. We can use that fact that dividing is optimal when faced with an even number.

We will represent n with a partial bitstring showing the least significant bits: X1, or X01, etc, where X represents the remaining bits, and is nonzero. When X is 0, the correct answers are clear: for 1, you're done; for 2 (0b10), divide; for 3 (0b11), subtract and divide.

**Attempt 1:** Check whether adding or subtracting is better with one bit of information:

1. Start: X1

   1. add: (X+1)0, divide: X+1 (2 operations)
   2. subtract: X0, divide: X (2 operations)

We reach an impass: if X or X+1 were even, the optimal move would be to divide. But we don't know if X or X+1 are even, so we can't continue.

**Attempt 2:** Check whether adding or subtracting is better with two bits of information:

1. Start: X01

   1. add: X10, divide: X1

      1. add: (X+1)0, divide: X+1 (4 operations)
      2. subtract: X0, divide: X (4 operations)
   2. subtract: X00, divide: X0, divide: X (3 operations)

      1. add: X+1 (possibly not optimal) (4 operations)

Conclusion: for X01, subtracting will result in at least as few operations as adding: 3 and 4 operations versus 4 and 4 operations to reach X and X+1.

2. Start: X11

   1. add: (X+1)00, divide: (X+1)0, divide: X+1 (3 operations)

      1. subtract: X (possibly not optimal) (4 operations)
   2. subtract: X10, divide: X1

      1. add: (X+1)0, divide: X+1 (4 operations)
      2. subtract: X0, divide: X (4 operations)

Conclusion: for X11, adding will result in at least as few operations as subtracting: 3 and 4 operations versus 4 and 4 operations to reach X+1 and X.

Thus, if n's least significant bits are 01, subtract. If n's least significant bits are 11, add.

Answer (score 3):

If you consider the binary representation of any positive integer and the operations allowed you will come up with the following:

1. Any sequence of 1s will be dealt with by adding 1
2. Any 1 which is not part of a sequence will be dealt with by subtracting
   1
3. The total number of divisions required will be the either the number
   of binary digits or the number of binary digits minus 1 depending on
   whether the last operation was an addition of 1 resulting in an
   extra bit on the number ( e.g. 1111 would become 10000 requiring an extra division while 1000 would require a total of 3 divisions )
4. There is a special case for the number 3 (11) where subtracting one is faster than adding one requiring 2 steps , a subtraction and a division instead of 3 steps, an addition and 2 divisions.

Point being you don't really need to do any operations to count the steps. All you need to do is loop once through the bits of the number and identify how many of the above you encounter. Though every time an addition of one is to occur the bit left to the sequence of 1s will need to be switched to 1.

Here's a sloppy python implementation of the above concept:

```
def countSteps(n):
    count = 0
    k = bin(n)[2:]
    i = len(k)-1
    le = len(k)
    k = list(k)
    subs = 0
    adds = 0
    divs = 0

    if n == 1:
        return 0

    while i>=0:
        ones=0
        while k[i] == '1' and i >=0:
            ones+=1
            i-=1

        if ones == 1 and i > 0:
            subs+=1
        if ones >1:
            #special case for 3
            if i < 0 and ones == 2:
                subs+=1
                divs-=1
            else:
                adds+=1
                k[i]='1'
                i+=1
        i-=1

    if k[1] == '1':
        divs = divs+le
    else:
        divs = divs+le-1

    return divs + subs + adds
```

This approach is likely to be very fast. Significantly faster than any approach requiring modulo to determine the next step.

Answer (score 2):

To solve the above problem you can either use recursion or loops
A recursive answer is already provided so i would try to give a while loop approach.

**Logic**: We should remember that the number multiple of 2 would always have less set bits than those which are not divisible by 2.

To solve your problem i'm using java code. I have tried it with few numbers and it works fine, if it doesn't add a comment or edit the answer

```
while(n!=1)
    {
        steps++;
        if(n%2 == 0)
        {
            n=n/2;

        }
        else
        {
            if(Integer.bitCount(n-1) > Integer.bitCount(n+1))
            {
                n += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                n -=1;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(steps);
```

The code is written in a very simple form so that it could be understood by everyone. Here **n** is the number entered and **steps** are the steps required to reach 1

Comment: This function gives the wrong result for 59. It returns 9 steps, while the correct answer is 8. The first step it does for 59 is -1, while it should choose +1. The counting of set bits is thus not a sound basis to find the shortest path. Also:  the statement in the "logic" paragraph is not correct: 5 (odd) has 2 set bits, while 14 (even) has 3. The statement needs to be further qualified to make it correct.

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea by squeamish ossifrage of greedily looking (for the case of odd numbers) whether *n + 1* or *n - 1* looks more promising, but think deciding what looks more promising can be done a bit better than looking at the total number of set bits.

For a number `x`,

```
bin(x)[:: -1].index('1')
```

indicates the number of least-significant 0s until the first 1. The idea, then, is to see whether this number is higher for *n + 1* or *n - 1*, and choose the higher of the two (many consecutive least-significant 0s indicate more consecutive halving).

This leads to

```
def min_steps_back(n):
    count_to_1 = lambda x: bin(x)[:: -1].index('1')

    if n in [0, 1]:
        return 1 - n

    if n % 2 == 0:
        return 1 + min_steps_back(n / 2)

    return 1 + (min_steps_back(n + 1) if count_to_1(n + 1) > count_to_1(n - 1) else min_steps_back(n - 1))
```

To compare the two, I ran

```
num = 10000
ms, msb = 0., 0.
for i in range(1000):
    n =  random.randint(1, 99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)

    ms += min_steps(n)
    msb += min_steps_back(n)

print ms / num, msb / num
```

Which outputs

```
57.4797 56.5844
```

showing that, on average, this does use fewer operations (albeit not by that much).

Comment: Should be `if n in [0, 1]: return 1-n`, but otherwise this looks good :-) +1

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Thanks! Once again, really liked your answer (can't upvote it more than once).

Comment: The division should be an integer division (`//` instead of `/`). Also: this function gives the wrong result for 3, 6, 11, 12, 13, and many others: in all these cases it returns 1 step more than the optimal solution.

Comment: @trincot Thanks, I'll check it. In any case, my answer is just a heuristic, not an optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am really bad at binaries so not counting the lsb or msb. 
What about below program -

```html
public class ReduceNto1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count1 = count(59);//input number
        System.out.println("total min steps - " + count1);
    }
    static int count(int n){
        System.out.println(n + " > ");
        if(n==1){
            return 0;
        }
        else if(n %2 ==0){

            return 1 + count(n/2);
        }else{
            return 1 + Math.min(count(n-1), count(n+1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it return 8 for 59. It returns 5 for 15

Comment: I think you would not be able to solve it for large numbers

Answer (score 1):

Although everyone has already answered the question with in depth analysis, I want to share one intuition for the readers. (Note: There is no formal proof in my answer)

- We can agree that it is better to divide by 2 when number is even.
- Now for the odd case consider last 2 LSBs of n.
- Case 1: 01 -> If we subtract 1 they will become 00 allowing us to divide 2 times in the subsequent steps. (As opposed to adding 1 which will make them 10)
- Case 2: 11 -> If we add 1 they will become 00 allowing us to divide 2 times in the subsequent steps. (As opposed to subtracting 1 which will make them 10). Special case is 3 as already discussed in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

The solution offered by Ami Tavoy works if the 3 is considered (adding to 4 would produce `0b100` and `count_to_1` equals 2 which is greater than subtracting to 2 for `0b10` and `count_to_1` equals 1).  You can add two steps when we get down no n = 3 to finish off the solution:

```
def min_steps_back(n):
count_to_1 = lambda x: bin(x)[:: -1].index('1')

if n in [0, 1]:
    return 1 - n

if n == 3:
    return 2

if n % 2 == 0:
    return 1 + min_steps_back(n / 2)

return 1 + (min_steps_back(n + 1) if count_to_1(n + 1) > count_to_1(n - 1) else min_steps_back(n - 1))
```

Sorry, I know would make a better comment, but I just started.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This looks like a comment to the question instead of an answer. If you intend to comment, you need to have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. Also check this [what can I do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 0):

As @trincot pointed out, we should always try to divide by two the number so, but one easy way to see why if the number is odd we should decrease by 1 if it's 3 or ends it "01", and add 1 in the other case is this. If n is odd, n % 4 will be 1 or 3, then n+1 or n-1 are going to be multiples of 4, which means that we are going to be able to divide twice the number by two.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: @CarySwoveland they don't have the reputation required to comment

Answer (score 0):

Based on @trincot answer, an alternative way to verify the 2 LSB's is simply using `bin(n)[-2:]` and voila for those who don't want to deal with binaries!

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: @CarySwoveland they don't have the reputation required to comment

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution in Java with a time complexity of O(1):

```java
int solution(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    int plus1Operations = ((n >> 1) & n) | ((n >> 1) & ~n); //(Over)estimate how many "+1" operations are required
    plus1Operations &= ~(n + plus1Operations);              //Adjust the estimate

    if(plus1Operations > (n >> 2))  //If by mistake we used the "+1" operation with 3
        count = -1;                 //Start counting from -1

    //Do all operations "+1"; each remaining bit set to 1 in 'n' means a "-1" operation, except for the most-significant bit set to 1
    n += plus1Operations;

    count += Integer.bitCount(n | plus1Operations);               //Count all "+1" and "-1" operations
    count += Integer.SIZE - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(n) - 2;  //Count all "/2" operations
    
    return count;
}
```

The idea behind this solution is that we don't have to reduce `n` to 1 to find how many operations are needed to reduce `n` to 1; in other words, we don't have to show anyone the steps required to reduce
to 1, what we really care about are:

- How many "+1" operations are needed?
- How many "-1" operations are needed?
- How many "divided by 2" operations are needed?

To do this, I used some primitive binary operations to create the `plus1Operations` placeholder, where each bit set to 1 indicates a "+1" operation; after that, I did all the "+1" operations in one go (`n += plus1Operations;`), thus transforming `n` into a placeholder where each bit set to 1 indicates a "-1" operation.

And finally, the [Hamming weight algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) is used to count the bits set in `n | plus1Operations`, while to count the operations "divided by 2", just count how many bits there are to the right of the most significant bit set to 1 of `n`.

To handle numbers up to 300 digits, just transform this algorithm using the class [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) instead of `int`.

You can find the full explanation of this algorithm here:
https://github.com/parmi93/fuel-injection-perfection

Comment: *"time complexity of O(1)"*: Your code is limited to `int` input, and not arbitrarily large integers. Asymptotic complexity implies that the input cannot be restricted to `int`. This function does not work for an input like 123456789123456. Once you turn this into a function that can take a `BigInteger`, it will not be O(1).

Comment: @trincot The original question by @natydn52 specifies that the maximum size of `n` is 10^300, so since we don't have to handle arbitrarily large integers, this algorithm has a time complexity of O(1).

Comment: But the point is that your program doesn't work for 10^300, and as for determining the time complexity you are *relying* on the cap on the input, you're not really giving *asymptotic* complexity. "Asymptotic" means you *don't* rely on that. And time complexity is about *asymptotic* complexity. It is meaningless if you rely on a limit on the input.

Comment: What I provided is the time complexity bounded by the size of the input.
In CS when we talk about complexity by "default" we usually mean in the size of the input, because otherwise not even basic operations such as comparing two variables, shift, addition, etc... cannot be considered operations with a linear time complexity.
"But the point is that your program doesn't work for 10^300": if you want you can easily create your own class (like `Integer10_300`) that supports operations such as right shift, negate, xor, etc.. adapting this algorithm for input of 10^300 with a O(1) time complexity

Comment: *"Time complexity bounded by the size of the input"*: that makes no sense.

Comment: It makes sense, because otherwise almost no algorithm can be considered with linear time complexity, even a simple `printf(int n);`
There is an interesting discussion about this topic here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/159696/measuring-time-complexity-in-the-length-of-the-input-v-s-in-the-magnitude-of-the